# Acceder a un arreglo que está dentro de otro - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy almacenando el carrito en mi base de datos una vez realizada la compra y consigo acceder a todos los datos, pero no se como acceder a otro arreglo que hay dentro que se llama `options` y de ahí dentro quiero sacar la medida y la marca.

**Esto es lo que recibo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Así hago el foreach para recorrer el carrito y almacenarlo en la bd:**

```
foreach ($cart as $key => $order) {

        $data = json_decode($order, true); 
        foreach($data as $item){
            $opt = new Order;
            $opt->id_cliente = $request->input('idusuario');
            $opt->fecha = date('j/n/Y');
            $opt->cliente = $request->input('persona');
            $opt->dni = $request->input('dni');
            $opt->producto = $item['name'];
            $opt->medida = 'medida';
            $opt->marca = 'marca';
            $opt->precio = number_format($item['price'], 2); 
            $opt->cantidad = $item['qty'];
            $opt->subtotal = number_format($item['subtotal'], 2); 
            $opt->iva = number_format($item['tax'], 2); ;

            $formateado = $item['subtotal'] + $item['tax'];

            $opt->total = number_format($formateado, 2);
            //$opt->factura = $idpedido .'.pdf';
            $opt->idpedido = $idpedido;

            $opt->metodo = $request->input('metodoPago');
            
            $opt->save();
        } 
        
    }
```

Pero al igual que accedo a los datos del arreglo de este modo `$item['qty']` como puedo acceder a lo que está dentro de options y sacar la medida y la marca???

Comment: Probaste con `isset` para comprobar si viene vacio la medida?

Comment: Si justo ahora jejej! muchas gracias @CesarRomero ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes acceder de la siguiente manera al array, prueba si te funciona.

```
$item['options']['items']
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido @Aberl Recouso González, gracias por tu respuesta, si que funciona justo probe lo mismo y funciono. Te recomiendo que elabores una respuesta correcta y describiendo el porque de hacerlo así, para que le pueda servir a otra persona.

Comment: Por otro lado, medida puede darse el caso de que venga vacio, estoy probando de la siguiente manera pero sin éxito: `if(!is_null($item['options']['medida'])) {$opt->medida = $item['options']['medida'];}` Como puedo hacerlo?